# Finding what distribution a random variable has.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Mike has a gold coin with fair probability, and a silver coin with $1\over 3$ probability for Heads and $2\over 3$ for tails. He tosses the gold coin 120 times and the number of heads is denoted N. Then he tosses the silvered on N times. The number of heads is denoted S and the number of tails is denoted T. How does S distributes given T=30?

I already computed S's expeted value, which is 20. It has the binomial distribution of Bin(120,$1\over 6$). I don't know, however, how to find what kind of distribution S has given T has a known value. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you get the distribution of $T$ to be $\text{Bin}(120,1/6)$? You toss the silver coin $N\leq 120$ times (a random number), and each of these times, the probability of tails is $2/3$.

Comment: I have 120 experiments with two levels. For me to get a head in the silvered coin, I have to get in one experiment a head in the gold coint and then a head in the silvered one. I has the probability of $1\over 6$ to succeed. I don't get a head on the silvered one if I either get a tail in the gold one, or get a head in gold one but tail in the silvered one.It has a probability of $5\over 6$.

Comment: Isn't it $S$ that's $\text{Bin}(120,1/6)$? After all, it's the combination heads-heads (gold then silver) that has probability $1/6$. The combination heads-tails has probability $1/3$, which makes $T$ distributed as $\text{Bin}(120, 1/3)$.

Comment: You are right. I switched S and T because there original question is not in English and I thought it would confuse if I kept it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allready found that $S$ has binomial distribution with parameters
$120$ and $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Likewise you can find that $T$ has binomial distribution with parameters
$120$ and $\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$.

That enables you to find an expression for $P\left(T=30\right)$.

We have $$P\left(S=s\mid T=30\right)=\frac{P\left(S=s\wedge T=30\right)}{P\left(T=30\right)}$$
so what remains is finding an expression for $P\left(S=s\wedge T=30\right)$.

$P\left(S=s\wedge T=30\right)=P\left(S=s\wedge N=s+30\right)=P\left(S=s\mid N=s+30\right)P\left(N=s+30\right)$

Of course $N$ has binomial distribution $\left(120,\frac{1}{2}\right)$
and under condition $N=s+30$ the distribution of $S$ binomial with parameters $s+30$ and $\frac{1}{3}$.

If I didn't make mistakes then you will end up with again a binomial
distribution. This time with parameters $90$ and $p=\frac{1}{4}$.

It would not surprise me if there is a more elegant route to this
result.

Comment: (+1) Your answer looks good to me. Another way to view it (whether or not it's elegant is up to the reader :-) is as follows. If you label the gold coins $1,\ldots,120$ and do the same for the silver coins, you have $120$ pairs that can be HH, HT, or T*: $P(HH)=1/6,P(HT)=1/3,P(T*)=1/2$. (Trinomial dist'n) Given $T=30$ there remain $90$ pairs that must be HH or T*, with respective probabilities $\frac{1/6}{1/6+1/2}=1/4$ and $\frac{1/2}{1/6+1/2}=3/4$, so that $S\mid T=30$ is $Bin(90,1/4)$.

Comment: @MickA Ah, yes. This is a nice confirmation and exhibits indeed a more elegant route. I somehow *knew* there had to be one. Thank you.